# Returning HTTP 502 error code in RESTful api when upstream provider fails

Tags: rest, api, http

Busy building an API, and some parts of our API heavily depend on a third party.

When we are unable to connect to the 3rd party, or the connection fails, I simply returned an error 500. However, I was wondering if it wouldn't make more sense to return a 502 Bad Gateway or a 504 Gateway Timeout?

However, my interpretation is that it could only be relevant for proxies, and not for API's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case I would suggest to use `503 Service Unavailable` and use the *Retry-After* Header to specify the time the client should wait before retrying.

When it's a matter of RESTful APIs I always check [this super complete guide](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/), which contains all the answers for all the all the questions you will ever imagine.

> Service Unavailable - service is (temporarily) not available (e.g. if a required component or downstream service is not available) — client retry may be sensible. If possible, the service should indicate how long the client should wait by setting the Retry-After header.